# SQL command not properly ended help oracle

Tags: oracle

What's wrong with my query ?

```
select * into dumpfile 
from dual 'C:WWW\site.com\file.php' 
from filetables ;
```

> [Err] ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: what does file.php return ?

Comment: What is that link for?

Comment: file.php auto create ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * into dumpfile from dual 'C:WWW\site.com\file.php' from filetables ;
```

Syntax is definitely wrong here. You should be doing something like:

```
SELECT * 
INTO dumpfile 
FROM filetables
WHERE field = 'C:WWW\site.com\file.php';
```

Comment: [SQL]SELECT *
 
INTO dumpfile
 
FROM filetables

WHERE field = 'C:WWW\site.com\file.php'

[Err] ORA-00904: "FIELD": invalid identifier

Comment: Use a field that exists n your schema fieltable where you store url. I used field just as an example to show how you could use SQL.

Comment: not schema I'm tables 'filetables' to C:WWW\site.com\file.php

Comment: Is "C:WWW\site.com\file.php" an alias?

Comment: I want to transfer the contents of the table to PHP. path : C:WWW\site.com\file.php

Comment: @MaviPeri It is not appropriate to StackOveflow to ask an other question in a comment. My guess is we have an instance of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here. May I suggest you to take some time to think about _what_ you are trying to do, and _ask an other question about that_.